# I don't know which one to pick

Tags: customization

When changing to OpenCL blender gives me the following options:
[image]

I know that these are names for AMD cards, but which one should I pick. Also I don't think I have that many AMD cards considering I have a laptop...

I am confused any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to me your computer has indeed several GPUs, two cores built into the CPU (Bristol Ridge) and a couple extra called Iceland (Radeon). Try the option that uses all of them and run a few tests to see which configuration works more efficiently. Run the [blenchmark](http://blenchmark.com/) with each configuration and decide based on that. Be aware also that AMD GPUs have still limited support on Cycles.

Comment: Aye will try and get back to you

Comment: @cegaton tried using Bristol Ridge(2x)+Iceland(2x) option but the BlenchMark addon gives me an error and asks me to pick the ones that are actually installed... Also I am still testing the others

Comment: However when I use the 4 of them separately It renders them just fine... I dunno why this is happening.